# App crashed when i am resuming after long time which is in background

Tags: android, onresume

My app is showing "not responding" when activity resume from background after long time.When i click on "Ok" for closing the app then app appears. I am not using OnResume method. I am getting below error

```
Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, 
android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seconds);

    if(!isMyServiceRunning(serv.class))
     {
        startService(new Intent(this, serv.class));
     }

    status = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);
    btn_send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(this);
    contlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contlist);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String y = prefs.getString("mobstat",null);
    status.setText(y);
    status.setSelection(status.getText().length());
    if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false))
    {
        try
        {
            getNumber(seconds.this.getContentResolver());
        } catch (JSONException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
        nonstoprun();
}



private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass)
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void nonstoprun()
{
    handler = new Handler();
    update = new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          musers = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
          descAdapter = new DescAdapter(seconds.this, musers, seconds.this);
          contlist.setAdapter(descAdapter);
          handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    };
          handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
}
```

I searched for the above error but there is no answer to solve this problem. The same problem when i am opening the app after long time.

Comment: Please provide logs

Comment: I am getting only the error which i mentioned in the question above.

Comment: The error message seems unrelated to the problem. Do you use static variables to store things?

Comment: There is a variable which stores the URL                                                      public static final String FetchURL = "http://xxxx.com/cont.php"
    public static final String FetchURL1 = "http://xxxx/mobpost.php"

Comment: you have to provide more logs, what you show up-there is neither relevant nor enough to analyze your issue

Comment: I am not getting logs. Its just showing app is not responding and pop up with ok and Wait.

Comment: Try to capture it through adb